Why does Deno.Command seem to capture stdout/stderr _without_ setting "piped"?
Here is the page I'm referencing: https://docs.deno.com/api/deno/~/Deno.Command
It says: If any stdio options are not set to "piped", accessing the corresponding field on the Command or its CommandOutput will throw a TypeError.
However, there are examples on that page that 1) do not set any stdio options to "piped" and 2) access fields 'stdout' and 'stderr' on a CommandOutput object. For example:
const command = new Deno.Command(Deno.execPath(), {
  args: [
    "eval",
    "console.log('hello'); console.error('world')",
  ],
});
const { code, stdout, stderr } = await command.output();
console.assert(code === 0);
console.assert("hello\n" === new TextDecoder().decode(stdout));
console.assert("world\n" === new TextDecoder().decode(stderr));

What am I missing here?

If you click on CommandOptions at the URL in your question, you can see the documented default values for the properties stdin, stdout, and stderr.

In some usage modes, "piped" is the default. Quoting from the code:
    /** How `stdin` of the spawned process should be handled.
     *
     * Defaults to `"inherit"` for `output` & `outputSync`,
     * and `"inherit"` for `spawn`. */
    stdin?: "piped" | "inherit" | "null";

    /** How `stdout` of the spawned process should be handled.
     *
     * Defaults to `"piped"` for `output` & `outputSync`,
     * and `"inherit"` for `spawn`. */
    stdout?: "piped" | "inherit" | "null";

    /** How `stderr` of the spawned process should be handled.
     *
     * Defaults to `"piped"` for `output` & `outputSync`,
     * and `"inherit"` for `spawn`. */
    stderr?: "piped" | "inherit" | "null";

Thus, if you don't specify otherwise, "piped" is used by default when calling output() or outputSync(), whereas "inherit" is the default when calling spawn().

Thank you. That explains it. I still think that that information should be included on the page I referenced rather than on a linked page, but now I understand.
